# Databinding: Having data reflect changes of a control's value that was modified via code

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have databinding between a control and a DataView.  All the databinding works, except for when I update the value of the control's databound field via code.  This value does not get reflected in the DataView.  If I click into the control's field this then becomes reflected in the data.  Any suggestions?  Calling update on the binding manager causes the control to then reflect what is in the data.  But I need some way of causing the data to ask for the newest values from the controls.

Let me know if I can clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code because this is an issue often solved using a BindingList, or an ObservableCollection and implementing INotifyPropertyChanged for the container object?

Answer (score 0):

`binding.BindingManagerBase.EndCurrentEdit();` ?

the binding is:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("Text", datasourceObject, property);
control.DataBindings.Add(binding);
```